# c# TcpClient and java ServerSocket

Tags: c#, java, sockets

hello i am making a server which will listen on port 6112 and say if the client connected to it,i have tried doing it in both languages..however it listens to connection and doesnt detect anything..any help?

heres the code for instance:

```
public static ServerSocket Start() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Initializing Network Listener");
    Config.Initialize();
    int netport = Config.netport;
    String netip=Config.netadress;
    ServerSocket Listener = new ServerSocket(netport);
    System.out.println("Done initializing Network Listener");
    Listener.setSoTimeout(0);
    return Listener;
}

public static void ListenForClient() throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket Listener = Start();
     Listener.setSoTimeout(0);
    Socket Client = Listener.accept();
    Client.setSoTimeout(120000);
    System.out.println("Client Connected on port: ");        


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=== UPDATE ===

- For a Java server socket client, here are two good examples:

> ```
> * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html
>
> * http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/EchoServer.java
> ```

2) For a C# server socket client, look here:

> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx

3) An easy way to test is:

> a) Start a command prompt
>
> b) `telnet localhost  6112`
>
> <= This should also connect to your server, without having to worry
>   about any Java client programming

4) If "telnet not found" on Windows, just go into Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, Add/Remove windows features.  For example:

> - [How to Enable Telnet Client in Windows 7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx)

... BUT ...

5) Perhaps the entire problem might be Windows firewall blocking your test port (6122).  Try this:

> - [Block/Unblock Programs in Windows Firewall](http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall.html)

Comment: Bind is done by ServerSocket constructor with int param. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)

Comment: thanks for the replies...by the way is there a way to make the serversocket listen on a proxy? kinda set the ip of my server to lets say 78,96,32,154..thanks

Comment: Hi - glad it helped.  And Thanks to Fildor for the constructive corrections - definitely appreciated!  Q: Can Java networking API use proxies?  A: Yes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html.  Q: Can Java *be* proxy?  A: Yes: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm